# Why is Lambda returning 502 server error on this simple function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Here is my simple function:

```
'use strict';

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

let myMessage = "Testing this message thing.";
callback(null, myMessage);

};
```

Yet whenever I run it, I get a 502 Internal Server Error.

Here are the logs:

```
2018-04-24T01:08:24.731Z    fcd84d74-475b-11e8-b29c-773ba9f4ad9c    Loading function
START RequestId: fcd84d74-475b-11e8-b29c-773ba9f4ad9c Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: fcd84d74-475b-11e8-b29c-773ba9f4ad9c
REPORT RequestId: fcd84d74-475b-11e8-b29c-773ba9f4ad9c  Duration: 9.04 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB  
START RequestId: 0558d0e2-475c-11e8-a47c-7df3b9f2c46d Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 0558d0e2-475c-11e8-a47c-7df3b9f2c46d
REPORT RequestId: 0558d0e2-475c-11e8-a47c-7df3b9f2c46d  Duration: 4.93 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB
```

Is there something I'm missing here?  This should be pretty basic stuff.

TTAIA

Comment: What environment.

Comment: You mean language?  Node.js

Comment: I mean lambda supports three node.js versions. Anyway your code looks fine. Upload cloudwatch logs.

Comment: what permission have you given?

Comment: Is this an API Gateway Lambda integration or Lambda@Edge?

Comment: @IvandelaBeldad Node.js 6.10 - will update with logs.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot API Gateway

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan Simple Microservices and Open

Comment: Did you test Lambda function in AWS console before test it through API Gateway?

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan Yes, it succeeds. Returns simply "Testing this message thing."

Comment: And just to confirm I'm doing this properly - the endpoint I'm trying to hit is the Invoke URL that is provided by the API Gateway Trigger entry.  That's the proper URL to hit, yes?

Comment: yes, you should use the URL generated by API Gateway. Also, I could see 'Loading function' written in log so wouldn't be an integration issue as well. I can't think anything on top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like the reason for the 502 is due to the fact that I was not returning an object.  I changed the code to what you see below. I've left in some of the commented lines to show what also worked (the Content Type I changed to text/html just to see if it would return true HTML, and it did), and what is left is the bare-minimum I needed to get the response successfully.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var responseBody = "Hi there";

    var response = {
        // "statusCode": 200,
        // "headers": {
        //     "Content-Type": "text/html"
        // },
        body: responseBody
        // "isBase64Encoded": false
    };

    callback(null, response);
};
```

I hope this helps others who are struggling with this.